# JQGrid resizable black bars

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, resize, jquery-ui-resizable

I've got a couple JQGrids across my site that I'd like to make resizable as in http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/.  But when I call $("#grid").resizable() it creates thick black lines on the right side and bottom of my grid.  I can click and drag these, and it looks like it's expanding the potential size of the grid, but the grid stays the same size.  Is there something else I need to do for it to work with JQGrid?

EDIT:  I've gotten the grid to resize properly using $("#grid").jqGrid('gridResize') but it still creates the ugly black bars on the right side and bottom of the grid.  Any tips on getting rid of these??

Comment: What you actually want? do you want to resize grid?

Comment: Yes, I don't care about having dynamic column sizes or number of rows, but just the display of the grid to resize properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed to do

```
$(".ui-resizable-e").width("0px")
$(".ui-resizable-s").width("0px")
```

.width(0) works as well.